# Localization (internationalization) in Angular 4+ using ngx-translate?

Tags: html, angular, localization, internationalization, ngx-translate

I am doing localization in Angular. I am not sure how to do localization for async observables.

Here I do it in for regular html without using async.

```html
<p class="pageTwo" [translate]="'users.licenses'">
  Licenses purchased
</p>
```

I am not sure how to implement the ngx-translate library for async pipe.

```html
<p class="availablelicenses">
  {{ numberOfLicensed$ | async }}
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
<p class="availablelicenses" [translate]="'usersPage.numberLicense'" [translateParams]="{number: numberOfLicensed$ | async}"></p>
```